# Floating Point Exception for seemingly no reason

Tags: c++

My code is throwing me a floating point exception here, but I can't figure out why.

```
int i = this -> numerator;
while(i > 1){
    if ((this -> numerator % i == 0) && (this -> denominator % i == 0)) {
        this -> numerator = this -> numerator / i;
        this -> denominator = this -> denominator / i;
    }
    i = i - 1;
}
```

The goal is to simplify a fraction. As you can see, things only get mod by i and i > 1. Same goes for division. Strangely it will keep throwing the error even if I comment out the code within the while loop, but the code works fine if I get rid of the while loop completely. The same thing happened when I tried to use a for loop instead. What am I missing?

Comment: Please remove all those `this -> `s. They're meaningless and distracting.

Comment: How large is `i` at loop entrance, and what are values of `*this`?  For that matter, what is the type of `numerator` and `denominator`?

Comment: Show a full code example that doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have compiler warnings enabled and, if so, are there any?

Comment: Note: Division/Remainder by `int` 0 is often reported as _Floating Point Exception_.  Maybe another part of code?

Comment: Have you used a debugger? what are the values of `i`, `numerator` and `denominator`.

Comment: This `while` is probably better written as `for(int i = numerator; i > 1; --i)`

Comment: If you want to simplify a fraction, I'd suggest to just divide both numerator and denominator by gcd( numerator, denominator ). (Greatest common divisor), that's way more efficient. You can get GCD by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281661/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-the-gcd-of-two-numbers

Comment: Is `this -> denominator  > 0` always true?

Comment: The code is for a class Mixed so I need the this ->. I originally had it in the for loop you suggested, but changed it to a while loop to see if it would fix my error. For this example, denominator and numerator are 20 and 12 respectively. There are no compiler errors. I cannot use GCD. This is for a hw assignment and the libraries we are allowed is restricted.

Comment: What type `numerator, denominator` fields?  `int`?

Comment: numerator and denominator are both of type int, yes

Comment: @JamesMatherly "this->" is not necessary in a class, unless you have variable/function shadowing. If you do, fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Strangely it will keep throwing the error even if I comment out the code within the while loop,

Then your problem is not in this bloc of code. Which, so far, I compiled and run with no error.

> but the code works fine if I get rid of the while loop completely

Then, it's likely you are doing something with variable `i` after this bloc of code that makes the floating point exception.

Run your code with a debugger to check where it fails.

Comment: You're right. It's telling me there's an error in a different member function. Thanks! (a totally different block that doesn't contain i since i wouldn't be in scope, though)

Comment: Right, then accept the answer to close the question.

Comment: No, accepting an answer doesn't close the question, and this is not an answer. But the question should be and has been closed as not satisfying the requirements for such a question on this site.

Comment: @Lightness: I respect your pov, though, the question was "What am I missing ?", so my reply answers the question. Moreover, I hope it also learns to OP not to believe in a seemingly obvious assumption, when facts contradict it. Anyway, you're right that this question is kind of topic and that I improperly used the term "close".