# Greatest Common Factor in o(1)?

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

Note: This is not asking how to solve the GCF in O(n)

You have two integers, `n` and `i`. How can we (in pseudo-code) calculate `GCM(n, i)` in constant time, where `n` and `i` have the domain of `0 -> infinity`?

The only solutions I've seen use recursion or loops. I'd like to do it in constant time if that is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think that this is possible? Seems clearly impossible to me. By the way, you asked about GCD but wrote GCM -- I suspect that this is a typo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to find the GCD of two numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281661/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-the-gcd-of-two-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, technically this is possible, yes — for example, by creating a matrix of precalculated results. But this is hardly practical due to insane memory consumption.

**N.B.:** This method has an important prerequisite:

`n, i ∉ [0; ∞)`, but rather `n, i ∈ [0; M], M ∈ [0; ∞)` — i.e. the value range is arbitrarily large, but still fixed.

Otherwise, the very operation of reading `n` and `i` into memory would be asymptotically linear, making `O(1)` even theoretically impossible.

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling it was just not possible through traditional means. Interesting ideas though!

Comment: It needn't be a matrix, you could create a bitmask of all the factors of the numbers you need and do an `and` of the two bitmasks. It would be a very large table though.

Comment: How could it be possible when the question explicitly says the range of `i`, `n` are 0 to infinity? You can't precompute infinitely many answers.

Comment: @MarkRansom, bitmasks are not enough. Many numbers have multiple instances of the same prime in factorization: e.g., 20 = 2×2×5.

Comment: @JohnColeman, if input numbers are truly arbitrary, then the very task of reading them would take `O(n)`. Ergo, fixed range is a necessary prerequisite for `O(1)`.

Comment: @hidefromkgb that would be a problem if the bitmask contained only primes. I'm suggesting a bitmask of *all* divisors, not just primes. Obviously that means the bitmask will be very large.

Comment: @hidefromkgb Which is why OP's actual question is clearly impossible. In some trivial sense *everything* you do with actual computers is `O(1)` since we live in a universe of bounded storage, but that isn't a very useful perspective and isn't what people usually mean by `O(1)`.